# How to use header to select columns and formatting columns

Tags: excel, vba, loops

Can anyone help me to solve this problem that I couldn't figure it out for a while. I have an excel sheet with over 200 columns and the header of some columns contain same specific text. How could I format those columns which headers contains specific text only? Please see below chart of my data. For example, I would like to set the format of "Vendor price" as number, "Price date" as "Date" and clean all space on the columns "Vendor Part#". And I don't know how to let the vba looping to make it.

| Line | SKU# | XXX PART# | VENDOR PRICE | PRICE DATE | YYY PART# | VENDOR PRICE | PRICE DATE | ZZZ PART# | VENDOR PRICE | PRICE DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0001 | 0AA | AU111111 | 50.00 |  | 0.00 |  |  |  |  |  |
| 0002 | BB0 | AU222222 | 50.00 |  | 0.00 |  |  |  |  |  |
| 0003 | CC0 |  | 0.00 | BU111111 | 40.00 |  |  |  |  |  |
| 0004 | DDD |  | 0.00 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 0005 | EEE |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

And this is my code which only formatting the first column of Price.

```
Dim src As Worksheet
Dim acell As Range

For Each acell In src.Range("A1:IW1").Cells
    Set acell = src.Rows(1).Find(What:="PRICE", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart)
    If Not acell Is Nothing Then
            aCol = acell.Column
            src.Columns(aCol).NumberFormat = "0.00"
    End If
Next
```

And here is the revised one based on Tim's code. However, the trim function doesn't work after I revised Tim's code.

```
    Sub Tester()
    
    Dim src As Worksheet
    Dim acell As Range, nf, v
    '...
    '...
    For Each acell In src.Range("A1:IW1").Cells
        nf = "" 'clear numberformat
        v = UCase(Trim(acell.Value))   'get the column header
        Select Case True
            Case v Like "*DATE": nf = "mm/dd/yy"
            Case v Like "*PRICE": nf = "0.00"
            Case v Like "PRICE*": nf = "0.00"
            Case v Like "*PART#": nf = "@"
            Case v Like "*PART NO.": nf = "@"
            Case v Like "*PART#": TrimSpaces acell.Offset(1)
            Case v Like "*PART NO.": TrimSpaces acell.Offset(1)
            Case v Like "*PRICE*": TrimSpaces acell.Offset(1)
            Case v Like "PRICE": TrimSpaces acell.Offset(1)
        End Select
        'any number format to apply?
        If Len(nf) > 0 Then src.Columns(acell.Column).NumberFormat = nf
    Next
End Sub

'Trim spaces from a column of data, starting at cell `c`
Function TrimSpaces(c As Range)
    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In c.Parent.Range(c, c.Parent.Cells(Rows.Count, c.Column).End(xlUp)).Cells
        cell.Value = Trim(cell.Value)
        If cell.Value = "0.00" Then
           cell.Value = ""
        End If
    Next cell
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```vb
Sub Tester()
    
    Dim src As Worksheet
    Dim acell As Range, nf, v
    '...
    '...
    For Each acell In src.Range("A1:IW1").Cells
        nf = "" 'clear numberformat
        v = UCase(Trim(acell.Value))   'get the column header
        Select Case True
            Case v Like "*DATE": nf = "Date"
            Case v Like "*PRICE": nf = "0.00"
            Case v Like "*PART#"
                nf = "@"
                TrimSpaces acell.Offset(1)
            Case v Like "*PART NO."
                nf = "@"
                TrimSpaces acell.Offset(1)
        End Select
        'any number format to apply?
        If Len(nf) > 0 Then src.Columns(acell.Column).NumberFormat = nf
    Next
End Sub

'Trim spaces from a column of data, starting at cell `c`
Function TrimSpaces(c As Range)
    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In c.Parent.Range(c, c.Parent.Cells(Rows.Count, c.Column).End(xlUp)).Cells
        cell.Value = Trim(cell.Value)
    Next cell
End Function
```

Comment: Wow it works wonderful for fomatting columns. However, the trim function doesn't work after I updated it as Case v Like "*PART#": TrimSpaces acell.Offset(1) and add the replace 0 to blank in the function. Could you please advise how I could revise it? Tks.

Comment: I thought you needed to trim spaces?  Are you instead replacing zeros?  Can you update your question to add some examples of the type of values you have, and what they need to be converted to ?

Comment: Yes, I need to trim spaces since each value has space. But it also need to make part# as text rather than number or general. Otherwise, it would miss 0 or the part# would be different. Also I would like to clean those "0.00" to make data clean. Please see the updated example. Thank you!

Comment: In a `Select Case` only one case gets chosen - you can't have two `Case v Like "*PART#"` for example, as only the first one will run.  If you need to take two actions then add them both to the same Case. See my edit above